# Complex 'mean-value-theorem'-like property implies quadratic

Tags: complex-analysis, alternative-proof

One of my friend asked me the following problem:

> **Problem.** Suppose that $f$ is a holomorphic function on a convex open set $U$ which satisfies the following property: For all distinct $z, w \in U$, there exists $\zeta$ on the line segment joining $z$ and $w$ such that
>   $$ \frac{f(w) - f(z)}{w - z} = f'(\zeta). $$
>   Then show that $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most 2.

This problem was given in the lecture note right after some basic properties of complex differentiability are introduced.

I was able to prove this problem, though my argument relies on heavy machinery (such as inverse function theorem) which is beyond the chapter containing it.

> **Q.** My question is, is there any elementary solution?

For a reference, here is my *heavy* solution:

---

**Step 1.** If $f'' \equiv 0$ on $U$, there is nothing to prove. So we may assume that $f''(z_0) \neq 0$ for some $z_0 \in U$. Our goal is to show that

> **Claim.** There exists a neighborhood $V \subseteq U$ of $z_0$ such that for any $z \in V$,
>   $$ \frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0} = f'(z_0 + \tfrac{1}{2}(z - z_0)).$$

Indeed, assuming that this claim is true, we obtain

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n+1)}(z_0)}{(n+1)!} (z - z_0)^n
&= \frac{f(z) - f(z_0)}{z - z_0} \\
&= f'(z_0 + \tfrac{1}{2}(z - z_0))
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n+1)}(z_0)}{n! 2^n} (z - z_0)^n.
\end{align*}

Comparing coefficients of both sides, we have

$$f^{(3)}(z_0) = f^{(4)}(z_0) = \cdots = 0$$

and hence $f$ is a polynomial of degree at most 2 on $V$. Then by the principle of analytic continuation, this continues to hold on all of $U$ as desired.

**Step 2.** So it remains to prove the claim. To this end, notice that

- $g(z) := (f(z) - f(z_0))/(z - z_0)$ has removable singularity at $z = z_0$, hence extends to a holomorphic function on $U$.
- By the inverse function theorem, there exists a neighborhood $V \subseteq U$ of $z_0$ on which $f'$ is invertible. By shrinking $V$ further, we may assume that $V$ is convex.

From the assumption, we know that $g(V) \subseteq f'(V)$. Thus

$$ \zeta(z) := (f')^{-1}(g(z)) $$

is a well-defined holomorphic function on $V$ such that

$$ \frac{\zeta(z) - z_0}{z - z_0} \in [0, 1] \quad \text{for all } z \in V \setminus\{z_0\}. $$

This implies that $(\zeta(z) - z_0)/(z - z_0)$ is constant, and this value can be determined by

$$ \frac{\zeta(z) - z_0}{z - z_0}
= \lim_{w \to z_0} \frac{\zeta(w) - z_0}{w - z_0}
= \zeta'(z_0)
= \frac{g'(z_0)}{f''(z_0)}
= \frac{1}{2}. $$

This completes the proof. ////

Comment: Your “heavy solution” already looks pretty elegant to me.